# Dynamic programming with Combination sum inner loop and outer loop interchangeable?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am a little confuse about the dynamic programming solution for combination sum, that you are given a list of numbers and a target total, and you want to count how many ways you can sum up to this target sum. Numbers can be reused multiple times. I am confused about the inner loop and outer loop that whether they are interchangeable or not. Can some explain the difference between the following two, and in what case we would use one but not the other, or they are the same.

```
int [] counts = new int[total];
counts[0] = 1;

// (1) 
for(int i = 0; i <= total; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
       if(i >= nums[j])
          counts[i] += counts[i - nums[j]];
   }
}

// (2)
for(int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++)
   for(int i = nums[j]; i <= total; i++) {
       counts[i] += counts[i - nums[j]];
   }
}
```

Comment: where does nums come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two versions are indeed different, yielding different results.

I'll use `nums = {2, 3}` for all examples below.

Version 1 finds the number of combinations **with ordering** of elements from `nums` whose sum is `total`. It does so by iterating through all "subtotals" and counting how many combinations have the right sum, but it doesn't keep track of the elements. For example, the count for 5 will be 2. This is the result of using the first element (with value 2) and finding 1 combination in `nums[3]` and another combination for the second element (value 3) with the 1 combination in `nums[2]`. You should pay attention that both combinations use a single 2 and a single 3, but they represent the 2 **different ordered lists** `[2, 3]` & `[3, 2]`.

Version 2 on the other hand find the number of combinations **without ordering** of elements from `nums` whose sum is `total`. It does so by counting how many combinations have the right sum (fur each subtotal), but contrary to version 1, it "uses" each element completely before moving on to the next element thus avoiding different orderings of the same group. When counting subtotals with the first element (2), all counts will initially be 0 (except the 0 sum sentinel), and any even subtotal will get the new count of 1. When the next element used, it is as if it's coming after all 2's are already in the group, so, contrary to version 1, only `[2, 3]` is counted, and not `[3, 2]`.

By the way, the order of elements in `nums` doesn't affect the results, as can be understood by the logic explained.

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic programming works by filling out entries in a table assuming that previous entries in the table have been fully completed.

In this case, we have `counts[i]` is dependent on `counts[i - nums[j]];` for every entry `j` in `nums`.

In this code snippet

```
    // (1) 
    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
           if(i >= nums[j])
              counts1[i] += counts1[i - nums[j]];
       }
    }
```

We fill the table in order from `0` to `total` *in that order*. This is the action of the outer loop. The inner loop goes through our different `nums` and updates the current entry in our table based on the previous values, which are all **assumed to be completed**.

Now look at this snippet

```
    // (2)
    for(int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++){
       for(int i = nums[j]; i < total; i++) {
            counts2[i] += counts2[i - nums[j]];
       }
    }
```

Here we are iterating through our list of different counts and updating our totals. This breaks the concept of dynamic programming. None of our entries can ever be assumed to be complete until we are completely finished with our table.

Are they the same? The answer is no they are not. The following code illustrates the fact:

```
public class dyn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int total = 50;
        int[] nums = new int[]{1, 5, 10};

        int [] counts1 = new int[total];
        int [] counts2 = new int[total];
        counts1[0] = 1;
        counts2[0] = 1;

        // (1) 
        for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
               if(i >= nums[j])
                  counts1[i] += counts1[i - nums[j]];
           }
        }

        // (2)
        for(int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++){
           for(int i = nums[j]; i < total; i++) {
                counts2[i] += counts2[i - nums[j]];
           }
        }

        for(int k = 0; k < total; k++){
            System.out.print(counts1[k] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for(int k = 0; k < total; k++){
                System.out.print(counts2[k] + ",");
        }

    }
}
```

This will output 2 different lists.

They are different because we are updating our `counts[i]` with *incomplete information* from earlier in the table. `counts[6]` assumes you have the entry for `counts[5]` and `counts[1]`, which in turn assume you have the entries for `counts[4]`, `counts[3]`, `counts[2]`, and `counts[0]`. Thus, each entry is dependent on (in the worst case *all of*) the previous entries in the table.

**Addendum:**

Interesting (perhaps obvious) side-note:

The two methods produce the same list up until the *smallest pairwise sum* of entries in nums.

Why?

This is when the information from previous entries becomes incomplete (with respect to the first loop). That is, if we have `int[] nums = new int[]{3, 6}`, then `counts[3+6]` will not be computed correctly, because either
`count[3]` will not be right or `count[6]` will not align with the result obtained using the first loop, depending on which stage of the computation we have done yet.

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong, and I think you didn't actually answer the question (other than showing the 2 versions are indeed different).

Comment: "Your conclusion is wrong", could you please be more specific so that I can correct it?

Comment: The order of elements in `nums` has no effect on the results (feel free to check).

Comment: I suspected that was your issue. Does the new revised wording make it clearer? I mean that `count[9]` will not align to version 1 because we have not made the pass that correctly updates previous values, which is indeed dependent on ordering.

Comment: Now I'm not entirely sure I understand that paragraph, but anyway I think it's "wrong" in the sense you're claiming a calculation is wrong when in fact it isn't.

Comment: Point taken - I had assumed through my whole discussion that the first loop was "right", because I could not see the use of the 2nd loop

Answer (score 0):

In light of criticism of my previous answer, I thought I'd take a more mathematical approach.

As in @Amit 's answer, I will use `nums = {2, 3}` in examples.

## Recurrence Relations

The first loop computes

S(n) = S(n-3) + S(n-2)

Or, more generally, for some set `{x_1, x_2, x_3, ... ,x_k}`:

S(n) = S(n- x_1) + S(n- x_2) + ... + S(n- x_k)

It should be clear that each `S(n)` is dependent on (possibly all) previous values, and so we must start on `0` and populate the table upwards to our desired `total`.

The second loop computes a recurrence S_2(n) with the following definitions:

S_1(n) = S_1(n-2)

S_2(n) = S_1(n) + S_2(n-3)

More generally, for some set `{x_1, x_2, x_3, ... ,x_k}`:

S_1(n) = S_1(n- x_1)

S_2(n) = S_1(n) + S_2(n- x_2)

...

S_k(n) = S_{k-1}(n) + S_k(n- x_k)

Each entry in this sequence is like those from the first loop; it is dependent on the previous entries. But unlike the first loop, it is also dependent on earlier sequences.

Put perhaps more concretely:

S_2 is dependent on not only (possibly all) previous entries of S_2, but also on previous entries of S_1.

Thus, when we want to compute the first recurrence, we begin at 0 and compute each entry, for each number in our `nums`.

When we want to compute the second recurrence, we compute each intermediate recurrence one at a time, each time storing the result in `counts`.

## In Plain English

What do these two recurrences compute? As @Amit 's answer explains, they compute the number of combinations that sum to `total`, with and without preserving order. It's easy to see why, again using our example of `nums = {2, 3}`:

Note my use of the word **list** to denote something ordered, and the word **set** to denote something unordered.

I use **append** to mean adding to the former, and **add** to denote adding to the latter.

## If you know

- how many **lists** of numbers add to 2,
- and how many add to 3,

## and I ask you

- how many add to 5?

You can **append** a 3 to every one of the former **lists**, and a 2 to every one of the latter **lists**.

Thus (how many add to 5) = (how many add to 3) + (how many add to 2)

Which is our first recurrence.

For the second recurrence,

## If you know

- how many **sets** of just `2`'s add to 5 (0)
- how many **sets** of just `2`'s and `3`'s add to 2 (1)

You can just take all of the first number, and you can **add** a 3 to all the **sets** in the second number.

Note how "**sets** of just `2`'s" is a special case of "**sets** of just `2`'s and `3`'s". "**sets** of just `2`'s and `3`'s" *depends on* "**sets** of just `2`'s", just like in our recurrence!

## Recursive functions written in java

The following recursive function computes the values for the first loop, with example values `3` and `2`.

```
public static int r(int n){
    if(n < 0)
        return 0;
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;
    return r(n-2) + r(n-3);
}
```

The following set of recursive functions computes the values for the second loop, with example values `3` and `2`.

```
public static int r1(int n){
    if(n < 0)
        return 0;
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;
    return r1(n-2);

}

public static int r2(int n){
    if(n < 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return r1(n) + r2(n-3);
}
```

I have checked them up to `10` and they appear to be correct.